# deserialize a generics hashmap when key is not primitive

Tags: generics, gson

I want to gson and de-gson a hashmap with generics.
I can do it successfully when my key is a string but not if it is an
object.
I have the two code part here . the first doesnt work and the second
does.

```
// doesnt work works
 try {
       TradableBean tradable = new TradableBean("Tradable");
       PositionBean position = new PositionBean(tradable);
       Map<TradableBean, PositionBean> map1 = new HashMap<TradableBean, PositionBean>();
       map1.put(tradable, position);
       String json1 = gson.toJson(map1);
       Map<TradableBean, PositionBean> map2 = gson.fromJson(json1, new TypeToken<Map<TradableBean, PositionBean>>(){}.getType());
       System.out.println(map2);
   } catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.println("failed");
   }
```

and now the working part -

```
 // works - with string
   try {
       String tradable = new String("Tradable");
       PositionBean position = new PositionBean(new TradableBean("Tradable"));
       Map<String, PositionBean> map1 = new HashMap<String,PositionBean>();
       map1.put(tradable, position);
       String json1 = gson.toJson(map1);
       Map<String, PositionBean> map2 = gson.fromJson(json1, new TypeToken<Map<String, PositionBean>>() {}.getType());
       System.out.println(map2);
   } catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.println("failed");
   }
```

and in the TradableBean I have:

```
@Override public int hashCode() {
   return getId();} 
@Override public boolean equals(Object obj) {
   boolean equals = false;
   if (obj instanceof AccountBean){
       TradableBean tradable_p = (TradableBean)obj;
       if (getId()==tradable_p.getId()){
           equals = true;
       }
   }
   return equals;
```

}

the exception:

> ```
> com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Expecting object found:
> "TradableBean{id=0, tradableName='Tradable', moneyMultiplier=1,
> expirationDate=null}"
>        at
> com.google.gson.JsonObjectDeserializationVisitor.visitFieldUsingCustomHandler(JsonObjectDeserializationVisitor.java:
> 100)
>        at
> com.google.gson.ObjectNavigator.navigateClassFields(ObjectNavigator.java:
> 150)
>        at com.google.gson.ObjectNavigator.accept(ObjectNavigator.java:123)
>        at
> com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContextDefault.fromJsonPrimitive(JsonDeserializationContextDefault.java:
> 84)
>        at
> com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContextDefault.deserialize(JsonDeserializationContextDefault.java:
> 53)
>        at com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters
> $MapTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultTypeAdapters.java:531)
>        at com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters
> $MapTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultTypeAdapters.java:498)
>        at
> com.google.gson.JsonDeserializerExceptionWrapper.deserialize(JsonDeserializerExceptionWrapper.java:
> 50)
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to write your own [custom serializator](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserializ).

**Update:** the tell-tale is the exception:

```
com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Expecting object found: "TradableBean{id=0, tradableName='Tradable', moneyMultiplier=1, expirationDate=null}"
```

The prepending string "TradableBean" seems to be written by a serialization that uses some sort of `toString()`. the Deserialization expected an object of the form `{id=0,... }`

Comment: Hi, I use the default serialization for TradableBean whenever I pass it and it works ok. It doesnt say in the api that it regular deserialization  shouldnot be used on a key for a map . Am I wrong?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the new data. I removed the prepending string but still no result. I tried also removing my toString. what exactly is it waiting to get in the toString of the key object? ? should I also write custom serialization ?

Comment: @450602: yes, custom serialization is a coin of two sides. most cases you need to implement both directions. Also, there's the strict flag on the Gson.decode()... see if that has any effect.

Comment: I can hardly find documentation on that. the link you sent me doesnt supply eaxaple. if you know of, it would be really nice if you put it here

Comment: @450602: sorry you didn't find it useful. it is, however, the most authoritative documentation there is. you may want to have a look at gson test suites here: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fgson%2Fsrc%2Ftest%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fgson

Answer (score 2):

Dan's answer is on the right track.

The Gson limitation you're bumping up against concerns how it currently serializes map keys: by calling `toString()`.  From [`MapTypeAdapter`](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/MapTypeAdapter.java):

```
map.add(String.valueOf(entry.getKey()), valueElement);
```

This behavior is also described in the `MapTypeAdapter` documentation.

> This implementation really only works well with simple primitive types as the map key. If the key is not a simple primitive then the object is {@code toString}ed and that value is used as its key.

If you insist on using custom types as map keys, then as best I can tell you're going to have to write a custom serializer and/or a custom deserializer and/or a `toString()` that generates a string representation that's easy to deserialize.

Also, take a look at [MapAsArrayTypeAdapter](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/MapAsArrayTypeAdapter.java) for one approach.  (It's usable with a call to `GsonBuilder.enableComplexMapKeySerialization()`, not through direct instantiation as the docs describe (because it's currently not a public class).  I didn't test it to see if its implementation works, but it looks promising.)